# ADB server didn't ACK (Asus Transformer Pad TF700T)

Tags: android, adb

I know there are several questions asking how to fix the "ADB Server Didn't ACK" error, however, none of them seem to have a fix to my solution.  In addition, the error seems to be isolated to one specific model of tablet (Asus Transformer Pad TF700T), since our Samsung tablet does not cause this problem.

I would like to know, why would the problem be isolated to one model of tablet, and is there any fix that I can try?  Does the Asus Transformer Pad TF700T have a history of such issues?

BTW I am running Windows 7 64 bit and am developing on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my TF700T, running Server 2008R2 and Android Studio. I had to manually install the OEM drivers for the tablet. You can get them here:

http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ASUS+Transformer+Pad+Infinity+TF700T&p=28&s=1

After installing the OEM drivers I reinstalled Android Studio and my TF700T was recognized. I'm up and running now. Hope that works for you.